# Alternate Access Mappings in different ports

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping, url, port

I've an WebApp using the 80 port and i have **extend it** - creating an AAM to Intranet Zone (http://my.new.url.com/). All good for now.

Now, i got a new WepApp for MySites in 81 port, but when i do the same config above mentioned the new url isn't working (http://my.sites.new.url.com:81/) and all i get is a *cannot display the webpage* message.

I've extend it with no :81 port, editing directly in IIS bindings and internal URLs also with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've done this, we actually extend our main web application to allow Search to run on the extended site since we use FBA on our main site.  When you see the error message do you get anything else in the ULS log or does the main page just not show up?

Comment: i already check ULS and as no reference to this issue at all, the only answer i get is "IE cannot display the webpage" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my fault! a tremendous failure...DNS alias was missing for the new url in :81 port, sorry about this dispensable question. WebApp Extend works fine and is a super feature in SP2010!

thanks dlongman, RubenHerman and MichaelF for your time and patience. regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go to your iis-manager and change the bindings of the mysite-site?

Comment: still not working...I have have 4 sites in IIS (2 of them where created by AAM)
WebApp:80 - WebAppMySites:81 - WebAppNewUrl - WebAppMySitesNewUrl:81

Comment: I don't think you should have 4 sites in IIS should you? I could be wrong but I thought the alternate access mapping allowed you to map a fake url to a real one to enable mapping between internal and external URLs or old server to new server migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the port number in the alternate access mapping. If the mapping is in the Internet zone remove the :81 from the URL. So your new mapping is just http://my.sites.new.url.com.

Comment: I try it in IIS and also in CA, removing the :81 directly in the Url on that AAM Collection...but with no success.